# ADF -pass SQL query in source with single quotes in date column

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass parameters in dynamic pipeline in source query inside data flow. Tablename and Column name is dynamic and will be passed through parameters. But i got an error while executing the below ADF query:

**ADF Query**: concat('SELECT ', $ValidationColumn, ' FROM ', $ValidationTable,' WHERE audit_datetime >= ', replace($StartAuditDateTime,'T',''),' AND audit_datetime <= ' ,replace($EndAuditDateTime,'T','') )

**Expected SQL query**: Select ID from Master where audit_datetime >= '2020-07-23 18:47:20.5666' AND audit_datetime <= '2020-07-24 01:47:20.5456'

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Can you show us the table schema?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below expression to form your query in your ADF Mapping dataflow expression builder.

```
"SELECT '{$ValidationColumn}' FROM '{$ValidationTable}' WHERE audit_datetime >= '{$StartAuditDateTime}' AND audit_datetime <= '{$EndAuditDateTime}'"
```

This will result in below QUERY formation:

```
SELECT ID FROM Master WHERE audit_datetime >= '2020-07-23 18:47:20.5666' AND audit_datetime <= '2020-07-24 01:47:20.5456'
```

Comment: I used this query and it works "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id = {$myVar}". I didn't need to specify single quotes around variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to escape single quote to get '{yourDateValue}' format,
you can do that like this `''''`

example:

```
@{concat('select * from [yourtable] WHERE [yourColumn] >=','''',{yourexpression},'''')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL syntax in Expression builder in ADF Data Flow where you need to use singe quotes

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE someColumn = 'Y'"
```